# How do process only certain XML nodes?

Tags: c#, xpath

This is my XML snippet (it has a root element).

```
<ItemAttributes>
    <Author>Ellen Galinsky</Author>
    <Binding>Paperback</Binding>
    <Brand>Harper Paperbacks</Brand>
    <EAN>9780061732324</EAN>
    <EANList>
        <EANListElement>9780061732324</EANListElement>
    </EANList>
    <Edition>1</Edition>
    <Feature>ISBN13: 9780061732324</Feature>
    <Feature>Condition: New</Feature>
    <Feature>Notes: BRAND NEW FROM PUBLISHER! 100% Satisfaction Guarantee. Tracking provided on most orders. Buy with Confidence! Millions of books sold!</Feature>
    <ISBN>006173232X</ISBN>
    <IsEligibleForTradeIn>1</IsEligibleForTradeIn>
    <ItemDimensions>
        <Height Units="hundredths-inches">112</Height>
        <Length Units="hundredths-inches">904</Length>
        <Weight Units="hundredths-pounds">98</Weight>
        <Width Units="hundredths-inches">602</Width>
    </ItemDimensions>
    <Label>William Morrow Paperbacks</Label>
    <ListPrice>
        <Amount>1699</Amount>
        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
        <FormattedPrice>$16.99</FormattedPrice>
    </ListPrice>
    <Manufacturer>William Morrow Paperbacks</Manufacturer>
    <MPN>006173232X</MPN>
    <NumberOfItems>1</NumberOfItems>
    <NumberOfPages>400</NumberOfPages>
    <PackageDimensions>
        <Height Units="hundredths-inches">120</Height>
        <Length Units="hundredths-inches">880</Length>
        <Weight Units="hundredths-pounds">95</Weight>
        <Width Units="hundredths-inches">590</Width>
    </PackageDimensions>
    <PartNumber>006173232X</PartNumber>
    <ProductGroup>Book</ProductGroup>
    <ProductTypeName>ABIS_BOOK</ProductTypeName>
    <PublicationDate>2010-04-20</PublicationDate>
    <Publisher>William Morrow Paperbacks</Publisher>
    <ReleaseDate>2010-04-20</ReleaseDate>
    <SKU>mon0000013657</SKU>
    <Studio>William Morrow Paperbacks</Studio>
    <Title>Mind in the Making: The Seven Essential Life Skills Every Child Needs</Title>
</ItemAttributes>
```

There are multiple "ItemAttributes" nodes, each having a different "ProductGroup" node.  I want only the first "ItemAttribute" where "ProductGroup" = "book:"

This is my C# code:

```
    XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(sr);
    XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

    // Compile a standard XPath expression
    XPathExpression expr;
    expr = nav.Compile("//ItemAttributes[contains(ProductGroup, 'Book')]");
    XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select(expr);

    // Iterate on the node set
    try {
        int x = iterator.Count;  //  <----------- count = 0
        while (iterator.MoveNext()) {  //  <-----------  finds nothing!
            XPathNavigator nav2 = iterator.Current.Clone();
            listBox1.Items.Add("price: " + nav2.Value);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
```

I know my code isn't correct, but I don't understand why the iterator.Count is zero!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `System.Xml.Linq`

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xmlstr)); 
var foundNode = xdoc
    .Descendants("ItemAttributes")
    .Where(node => node.Element("ProductGroup").Value == "Book")
    .First();

var price = foundNode.Element("ListPrice").Element("FormattedPrice").Value;
```

**--EDIT--**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xmlstr = @"
                    <root>
                    <ItemAttributes>
                    <Author>Ellen Galinsky</Author>
                    <Binding>Paperback</Binding>
                    <Brand>Harper Paperbacks</Brand>
                    <EAN>9780061732324</EAN>
                    <EANList>
                    <EANListElement>9780061732324</EANListElement>
                    </EANList><Edition>1</Edition>
                    <Feature>ISBN13: 9780061732324</Feature>
                    <Feature>Condition: New</Feature>
                    <Feature>Notes: BRAND NEW FROM PUBLISHER! 100% Satisfaction Guarantee. Tracking provided on most orders. Buy with Confidence! Millions of books sold!</Feature>
                    <ISBN>006173232X</ISBN>
                    <IsEligibleForTradeIn>1</IsEligibleForTradeIn>
                    <ItemDimensions>
                    <Height Units=""hundredths-inches"">112</Height>
                    <Length Units=""hundredths-inches"">904</Length>
                    <Weight Units=""hundredths-pounds"">98</Weight>
                    <Width Units=""hundredths-inches"">602</Width>
                    </ItemDimensions>
                    <Label>William Morrow Paperbacks</Label>
                    <ListPrice>
                    <Amount>1699</Amount>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <FormattedPrice>$16.99</FormattedPrice>
                    </ListPrice>
                    <Manufacturer>William Morrow Paperbacks</Manufacturer>
                    <MPN>006173232X</MPN>
                    <NumberOfItems>1</NumberOfItems>
                    <NumberOfPages>400</NumberOfPages>
                    <PackageDimensions>
                    <Height Units=""hundredths-inches"">120</Height>
                    <Length Units=""hundredths-inches"">880</Length>
                    <Weight Units=""hundredths-pounds"">95</Weight>
                    <Width Units=""hundredths-inches"">590</Width>
                    </PackageDimensions>
                    <PartNumber>006173232X</PartNumber>
                    <ProductGroup>Book</ProductGroup>
                    <ProductTypeName>ABIS_BOOK</ProductTypeName>
                    <PublicationDate>2010-04-20</PublicationDate>
                    <Publisher>William Morrow Paperbacks</Publisher>
                    <ReleaseDate>2010-04-20</ReleaseDate>
                    <SKU>mon0000013657</SKU>
                    <Studio>William Morrow Paperbacks</Studio>
                    <Title>Mind in the Making: The Seven Essential Life Skills Every Child Needs</Title>
                    </ItemAttributes>
                    </root>
                    ";
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xmlstr));
            var foundNode = xdoc
                .Descendants("ItemAttributes")
                .Where(node => node.Element("ProductGroup").Value == "Book")
                .First();

            Console.WriteLine(foundNode.Element("ListPrice").Element("FormattedPrice").Value);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

**--EDIT2--**

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIAAFYAPOR6SX5GOA&AssociateTag=pragbook-20&IdType=ISBN&ItemId=9780061732324&MerchantId=All&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Medium&SearchIndex=Books&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2012-02-26T20%3A18%3A37Z&Version=2011-08-01&Signature=r7yE7BQI44CqWZAiK%2FWumF3N4iutOj3re9wZtESOaKs%3D");
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01");
var foundNode = xdoc
    .Descendants(ns+"ItemAttributes")
    .Where(node => node.Element(ns+"ProductGroup").Value == "Book")
    .First();

Console.WriteLine(foundNode.Element(ns+"ListPrice").Element(ns+"FormattedPrice").Value);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: No it's c#. It is [Linq to Xml](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx) and under `System.Xml.Linq` namespace. I added a `<root>` tag to your xml and tested it before posting

Comment: Can't find System.Xml.Linq... tried adding it but it doesn't exist... ???  I found the following: Schema, Serialization, XPath and Xsl.

Comment: Which version of .Net Framework do you use? It may require >= 4.0

Comment: yep, it's 3.5... the project is about 7 years old... any other way to do this without going to 4.0?

Comment: I just created a .Net 3.5 project and pasted the code into it. It works.

Comment: Installed .NET 4.0... got this error:  XElement does not contain a definition for ".Where"

Comment: My test 3.5 project is open in front of me, and I can compile it without any error. Are you sure, you have copied it correctly? Since I alwasys run the code before posting.

Comment: @spokane-dude See my edit. I added the full-code that runs without any problem. Just create a console app. paste this code

Comment: Illegal characters in the path when using the response from Amazon...   u want to move this to chat?

Comment: This is the URL for complete response from Amazon...

http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIAAFYAPOR6SX5GOA&AssociateTag=pragbook-20&IdType=ISBN&ItemId=9780061732324&MerchantId=All&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Medium&SearchIndex=Books&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2012-02-26T19%3A53%3A09Z&Version=2011-08-01&Signature=6gnl3D6LtZZN533h5AQZWKS3fN09grroaKvittkS%2F0I%3D

Comment: I get `request has expired` error. Can you post a complete xml?

Comment: Here is the URL... XML is too long unless you want me to Dropbox it...

http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIAAFYAPOR6SX5GOA&AssociateTag=pragbook-20&IdType=ISBN&ItemId=9780061732324&MerchantId=All&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Medium&SearchIndex=Books&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2012-02-26T20%3A18%3A37Z&Version=2011-08-01&Signature=r7yE7BQI44CqWZAiK%2FWumF3N4iutOj3re9wZtESOaKs%3D

Comment: @spokane-dude OK I got your xml. I posted another code (EDIT2) It also works without any problem and prints `$16.99`. (See the *namespace* declaration which was not available in your original question)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I got $16.99!  Wheeeeeeeeee

I assume that I can now process ONLY that one node that has ProductGoup = Book, right?  The other nodes will NOT be available to process?

Comment: Yes. as from your question `I want only the first "ItemAttribute" where "ProductGroup" = "book:"`, foundNode is a `ItemAttribute` which satisfies your conditions. In fact, I only translated your words to c#

Answer (score 0):

I'd use XPath with `XmlDocument` to handle this.

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(myXMLString);

XmlNodeList nodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes("//ItemAttributes[./ProductGroup[text()='Book']]");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
  //Do anything with node.Value;
}
```

I haven't tried your code but from what I see your XPath expression was incorrect.
I have broken down the expression I wrote above, below.

It reads as

```
//ItemAttributes    #look for all nodes named ItemAttributes
[
    ./ProductGroup  #with a child node called ProductGroup
    [
      text()='Book' #that has the string 'Book' as the text
    ]
]
```

Comment: I tried this and it found nothing... I know it's there, so I guess it's still not working... I'm a newbie with XPath... I was told that THIS was the way to go, but it's just not finding the node... any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You say that your XML is a snippet.  I'm going to hazard a guess that it's contained within an element that binds the default namespace prefix to a non-trivial URI, and that this is why you're getting no results from your iterator.

Your code worked for me, with the XML document as given above.  I ran the code and got one element out of the iterator.  I then took your XML document and wrapped it in a root element that binds the default namespace prefix to a made-up but non-trivial URI:

```
<SomeRootElement xmlns="http://schemas.blahblahblah.com/example">
  <ItemAttributes>
    <!-- rest of your document omitted -->
  </ItemAttributes>
</SomeRootElement>
```

I then got no results from the iterator.

I then created an [XmlNamespaceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx) which mapped a prefix (I chose `pfx`) to the namespace URI used above:

```
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
mgr.AddNamespace("pfx", "http://schemas.blahblahblah.com/example");
```

I then set this namespace manager as the namespace context for the XPath expression, and added the prefix `pfx` to the names within your XPath expression:

```
XPathExpression expr;
expr = nav.Compile("//pfx:ItemAttributes[contains(pfx:ProductGroup, 'Book')]");
expr.SetContext(mgr);
XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select(expr);
```

I then got the one element out of the iterator, as expected.

---

XPath can be a bit funny with namespaces.  I tried binding the empty prefix `""` to the URI so that I could use your XPath expression unmodified, but that didn't work.  That's one thing I've found with XPath before: always bind namespace URIs to prefixes with XPath, even if the original XML document binds the default namespace prefix.  Unprefixed names in XPath always seem to be in the 'null' namespace.

I've not really looked into how you map namespace prefixes to URIs with XPath in .NET much, and there are probably better ways of doing it than what I've cobbled together after a quick Googling and reading of MSDN.

**EDIT**: the aim of my answer was to explain why your code using XPath didn't work.  You didn't understand why you were getting no results out of the iterator.  My suspicion was that you hadn't given me the full XML document, and that in the part of the document that you didn't share with us laid the answer.

Ultimately, I believe your original code didn't work because of [XML namespaces](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/1999/01/namespaces.html).  As I write this edit, I can only get a 'Request has expired' error from the URLs in your comment thread with L.B, so I can no longer test with the same kind of data you're using.  However, this error request does begin as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ItemLookupErrorResponse xmlns="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-08-01/">
```

The `xmlns` attribute puts the element, and every element contained within it, into a *namespace*.  Each namespace is identified by a URI, and together, the URI and the element name identify that element.

It could be that a successful request may have the same attribute.  However, L.B.'s answer uses a different namespace, so I can't be sure.  For the rest of this edit, I'll have to assume a successful request does contain the same namespace as an unsuccessful one.

Because of this namespace, the element `<ItemAttributes>` within this XML

```
<ItemLookupResponse xmlns="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-08-01/">
  <ItemAttributes />
</ItemLookupResponse>
```

and within this XML

```
<ItemAttributes />
```

are not the same.  The first is in the `http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-08-01/` namespace, whereas the second is in the namespace identified by the empty string.  This empty namespace is the default namespace if it hasn't been set any other way.

Because the two `ItemAttributes` elements have different namespaces, they're not the same.

As well as changing the namespace of elements by using `xmlns="..."`, you can also associate (or *bind*) a prefix to a namespace.  This is done by specifying the prefix you want to associate with the namespace in an `xmlns` attribute, using an attribute such as `xmlns:prefix="some-uri"`.  This prefix is then put in the XML element before the local name, for example `<prefix:SomeElement ... />`.  This puts the `SomeElement` element in the namespace associated with the URI `some-uri`.

Because elements are identified by local name and namespace URI, the following two XML fragments are equal, even though one uses a prefix and the other one doesn't:

```
<ItemLookupResponse xmlns="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-08-01/">
  <ItemAttributes />
</ItemLookupResponse>

<ecs:ItemLookupResponse xmlns:ecs="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-08-01/">
  <ecs:ItemAttributes />
</ecs:ItemLookupResponse>
```

Now we turn to XPath and namespaces.  Your XPath expression is

```xml
//ItemAttributes[contains(ProductGroup, 'Book')]
```

One irritation with XPath is that you can't change the namespace used without prefixes in the same way as you can with XML.  So the names `ItemAttributes` and `ProductGroup` in the above are always in the 'empty' namespace.  This XPath expression matches nothing in your XML document because there are no elements with local name `ItemAttributes` in the 'empty' namespace, let alone any with a `ProductGroup` child element containing the text `Book`.

However, with most (if not all) XPath APIs, there are ways of binding prefixes to namespaces.  What I did was to show one way of doing this with XPath in .NET.  I associated the prefix `pfx` (I could have chosen any prefix I wanted) with the URI I had used in my example above.  You'd use a different URI to my made-up example.  You could then use the XPath expression

```xml
//pfx:ItemAttributes[contains(pfx:ProductGroup, 'Book')]
```

to find the relevant element, because there are element(s) with name `ItemAttributes` and namespace `http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-08-01/`, and at least one of those contains a child element with name `ProductGroup` in the same namespace and with text contents `Book`.

Comment: The XML was obtained from the web (a call to Amazon, which returns XML as the response)... and this totally confuses me :D... sorry, can you make it a little simpler for my newbie brain?

Comment: @spokane-dude: I've now updated my answer, I hope it explains things a bit better.  XPath isn't always the easiest thing to use, and I don't blame you for deciding to use Linq to XML instead.  However, I hope my edit helps you understand why your iterator was returning a count of zero, which, ultimately, was the question you asked.